# R: Representative random sampling for 150 values from categories with different group size

Tags: r, random, dplyr, categories

I face the problem that I want to have 150 randomly drawn samples from a dataset based on two categories "site" and "species". So, ideally, we have an outcome of 30 samples per site where each species is more or less equally distributed.

Reproducible example:

`df <- data.frame(site = rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), each = 10), species = c("s1", rep("s2", each = 3), rep("s3", each = 16), rep("s4", each = 13), rep("s5", each = 17)), individual = c(1, 1:3, 1:16, 1:13, 1:17) )`

I think using the dplyr function group_by(site, species) and slice_sample() are a good approach which would however sample a certain amount per group and not 150 in total..
Another problem I have now is that slice_sample needs at least the n-amount of samples in each group to work. This is not always given. So, is there a possibility of sampling 150 in total and whenever the desired amount to sample per group is not provided, then just sample others for compensation?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you give more details about what do you mean by "species is more or less equally distributed"? Do you have constraints on the number of unique species per site (for example at least one species and max 10 or so)? Or do you refer that it terms of number of unique individuals as well? That is, sample from all combinations of sites and species, but not more than X individuals per such a group? etc. Is the column "individual" referring to the counts of individuals or is it their id?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to `nest_by(site)` and then use `slice_sample()` to draw a sample of 30 from each group. If needed we can use `tidyr::unnest()` to get one "normal" `data.frame` containing all samples drawn.

The problem is probably the condition that:

> where each species is more or less equally distributed

When we look at your `site`s we can see that most of the site only have one species. So drawing samples from your original data will lead to specific sites only containing a certain `species`. Alternatively, we could just sample `species` and assign a `site` randomly independent of the fact that this `species` has never been observed there.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

site_sample <- df %>% 
  nest_by(site) %>% 
  summarise(data = list(slice_sample(data, n = 30, replace = TRUE)))
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'site'. You can override using the `.groups`
#> argument.

site_sample
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#> # Groups:   site [5]
#>   site  data             
#>   <chr> <list>           
#> 1 A     <tibble [30 x 2]>
#> 2 B     <tibble [30 x 2]>
#> 3 C     <tibble [30 x 2]>
#> 4 D     <tibble [30 x 2]>
#> 5 E     <tibble [30 x 2]>

site_sample %>% 
  unnest(data)
#> # A tibble: 150 x 3
#> # Groups:   site [5]
#>    site  species individual
#>    <chr> <chr>        <dbl>
#>  1 A     s1               1
#>  2 A     s3               1
#>  3 A     s1               1
#>  4 A     s3               5
#>  5 A     s3               3
#>  6 A     s3               4
#>  7 A     s2               2
#>  8 A     s3               3
#>  9 A     s3               5
#> 10 A     s3               2
#> # ... with 140 more rows
```

original data

```r
df <- data.frame(site = rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), each = 10), species = c("s1", rep("s2", each = 3), rep("s3", each = 16), rep("s4", each = 13), rep("s5", each = 17)), individual = c(1, 1:3, 1:16, 1:13, 1:17) )
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks Tim, I will try the nest_by() function. There are two things: 1.) in my original data, on each site there are several species. some of them might however be represented with only 1 individual. 2.) I need a sampling with replace = False to avoid sampling the same individual. So would the approach still work?

Comment: EDIT: This approach unfortunately did not work because of the replace = FALSE necessity. So are there any other approaches to sample basically 150 individuals in total but try to catch at least three or so of of every species and when the species was occurring only once, then sample the one?